# asterisk Set custom field with channel function

Tags: server, asterisk, voip

Since CDR function is deprecated in Asterisk 13.
How to set a custom variable in realtime Database using CHANNEL(Mycustomfield)

I keep getting "func_channel_write_real: Unknown or unavailable item requested: Mycustomfield"

Before "CDR(Mycustomfield) = newvalue" used to work. and now "CHANNEL(Mycustomfield) = newvalue" does not.
 I am using asterisk 13.6.0
 Thanks

Comment: Are you sure with what you wrote? I've been doing Asterisk for 14 years, and I've never seen a CDR(mycustomfield) directive. I've seen CDR(userfield), that is a field you can use to set stuff in the CDR, but I'm not familiar with an arbitrary assignment.

Comment: cdr_adaptative_odbc.conf does it magically http://doxygen.asterisk.org/trunk/cdr_adaptive_odbc.conf

Comment: Can you please post your configurations to something like pastebin.com? I would like to try and reproduce your issue on my systems.